# Localhost - Root linking

Tags: localhost

I am building simple HTML pages and I want to use this kind of linking in the menu (each subpage is a index.html file in a subfolder...).

```
<a href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

This works fine on the actual domain. But when I build the website in my localhost this linking wont work. Any ideas of how I can make it work on both places (without changing the linking)?

Maybe there is something I can change in the host file? (I'm using Windows)

Comment: Which web server are you using, and are you absolutely sure the directory structure in your local document root is the same as on the live server?  Does the web server error log show 404s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose your site folder (yoursite) is at the path /some/path/yoursite and you want to access it with http://yoursite. Then you can create a /etc/hosts entry:

```
127.0.0.1 yoursite
```

and create the following entry in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:

```
<VirtualHost yoursite>
  DocumentRoot /some/path/yoursite
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart apache2, it should work.

Comment: you will have to locate the two files in your windows directory structure.

Comment: Thanks Umar, tough I have problem finding "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:". Can you explain the location from C: ? Thanks

Comment: Found it: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

Comment: @Hakan In XAMPP, your default document root is C:\xampp\htdocs\ As long as your directory structure is the same within that directory as on your live server, it should work.  If it doesn't, check the error log.

Comment: Made it using this guide: http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/